# Python: double integration on an infinite domain

Tags: python, integration, numerical-methods

I am trying to integrate my function over `u` and `xx` and then store the values in a matrix so I can plot them with `imshow` or `pcolormesh`.  The bounds on the integration are `0 < u < inf` and `-inf < xx < inf`.  At the moment, I am only taking the bounds to be 10 until I can figure this out.

```
import numpy as np
import pylab as pl
from scipy.integrate import dblquad

b = 50.0

x = np.linspace(-10, 10, 1000)
y = np.linspace(0, 10, 1000)

T = pl.zeros([len(x), len(y)])


for xi in enumerate(x):
    for yi in enumerate(y):
        def f(xi, yi, u, xx):
            return ((np.exp(u * (b - yi)) - np.exp(-u * (b - yi))) /
                    (np.exp(u * b) - np.exp(-u * b)) * np.cos(u * (xx - xi)))


def fint(u, xx):
    return T + dblquad(f, -10, 10, 0.1, 10, args = (u, xx))[0]
```

This is the code I have so far but I know it isn't working properly; unfortunately, I don't know what the problem is.  Maybe I can't have the two for loops in my definition of `f` or my my `fint` is wrong.

Comment: Yes, having a definition within a for loop is something I had never even consider. You do realize that since you define your function within the loop you are defining it a lot of times without using it (does that even work?). Also, I don't see you calling fint in the example, are you doing it later from outside or not at all?

Comment: @Jblasco I don't want to call fint any more.  The goal of my integration is to have some matrix of points I can plot as a heat map on a specified domain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not completely clear from your question what you're trying to do. But here's how I interpreted it: You have a double integral over two variables `u` and `xx`, which also takes two parameters `xi` and `yi`. You want to evaluate the integral over `xx` and `u` at many different values of `xi` and `yj`, and store these values in `T`. Assuming this is what you want to do (and correct me if I'm wrong), here's how I would do it.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import dblquad

b = 50.0

x = np.linspace(-10, 10, 1000)
y = np.linspace(0, 10, 1000)

def f(xx, u, xi, yj):
    return ((np.exp(u * (b - yj)) - np.exp(-u * (b - yj))) /
            (np.exp(u * b) - np.exp(-u * b)) * np.cos(u * (xx - xi)))

T = np.zeros([len(x), len(y)])
for i, xi in enumerate(x):
    for j, yj in enumerate(y):
        T[i, j] += dblquad(
            f, -10, 10, lambda x: 0.1, lambda x: 10, args=(xi, yj))[0]
```

Comment: You interpreted the question correctly.  Then I can just set up my plotting and do `pylab.pcolormesh(x, y, T)` or would it have to be `pylab.pcolormesh(x, y, T[i, j])`?

Comment: Also, I want to integrate u and xx so I need to change the arguments to that correct?

Comment: The first is correct: `pylab.pcolormesh(x, y, T)`. The latter would just pass one element of `T` to `pcolormesh`, but you want to pass all elements of `T`, so you just pass the whole `T` matrix.

Comment: In response to your second question: No, the way I have it now, my code above is doing is one million integrals over `xx` from -10 to 10 and `u` from 0.1 to 10, with each integral at a different point `(xi, yj)`. This code will take a long time, so you might want to start with `x = np.linspace(-10, 10, 30)` and the same for `y`, so that each just goes over 30 `xi` or `yj` points, and then you only have to do 900 integrals, but still have okay resolution. (Note: the `args` on `dblquad` are extra arguments passed to `f`, not the variables you're integrating over.)

Answer (score 0):

fint is the only thing that calls f. You are not calling fint, which means that f is not being used at all, just defined about a million times. I would consider defining the function just once and calling it a million times instead.